# how I can consolidate 2 different apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

currently have 2 separate apps module which are running based on their own ports (eg: localhost:8001 and localhost:8002). But the similarities is on their login page is logon based on email address and password.

Do you have any ideas on how to combine the login page become 1. then after login it will redirect to the main page of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some websites who give you options as to how one can login.
I recommend asking the user how they want to login(as in use username, use email id, etc) and redirect accordingly on success.

Let me know what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

a suggestion is to switch your URLs with taken.

i.e.

> login at 8001 with username and password
>
> redirect to 8002 with the received token from 8001
>
> User token in 8002 and if token expire then again send it to 8001 port for authentication